# Задать класс с порядковым номером слайду в slick slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Как сделать так чтобы на соответствующий по порядку слайд был определенный класс с номером слайда. Почти получилось, но к 3му слайду уже получаются 3 класса: style0, style1, style2, а нужно только style2

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/jeOMBw?editors=1011

```
// add classes

$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(currentSlide);
  $('.slide').addClass('style'+currentSlide);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проставить классы до инициализации слайдера.

```js
$('.slider .slide').each(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).addClass('style'+index);
})
$('.slider').slick({
  dots:true,
  arrows:false,
  customPaging:function(){return ''}
})
```

```css
html{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
*,:before,:after{
  box-sizing:inherit;
}
.slide{
  border:2px solid #ccc;
  background-color:gray;
  line-height:300px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:90px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.style0{
  color:red;
}
.style1{
  color:green;
}
.style2{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
```